# Doubly Linked List in java

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm having trouble with the methods. None of the output is right and I'm not sure if I'm using double linked lists correctly. Can someone correct or explain to me what I'm doing wrong?

```
public class SlideList 
{

    private SlideNode head;
    private SlideNode tail;
    private SlideNode cursor;

    public SlideList()
    {
        head = null;
        tail = null;
        cursor = null;
    }
    public void editCurrentSlide(String text, int lineNum) throws IllegalArgumentException 
    {
        if(cursor==null||lineNum>5||lineNum<0)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Slide does not exist");
        cursor.getSlide().setData(text, lineNum);
    }
    public boolean jumpToPosition(int position)
    {
        if(position<0 || position>listLength())
            return false;
        resetCursor();
        for(int x=1;x<=position;x++)
        {
            cursor = cursor.getNext();
        }
        return true;
    }
    public void displayCurrentSlide() throws EmptyListException
    {
        if(cursor==null)
            throw new EmptyListException("There is no list");
        displaySlide(currentSlide());
    }
    public void displaySlides(int start, int end) throws IllegalArgumentException
    {
        int length = listLength();
        resetCursor();
        if(start<1)
            start=1;
        if(end>length)
            end = length;
        if(start>length||length==0)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("There is no list");
        resetCursor();

        for(int i = 1; i < start; i++)//we can choose where to start the list with i
        {
            System.out.println("Inside loop1");
            cursor=cursor.getNext();

        }
        System.out.println("start: " + start + " end: " + end);
        for(int x = start; x<=end; x++)
        {

            System.out.println("Inside loop2");
            displaySlide(x);
            if(start<end)
                cursor = cursor.getNext();

        }
        //cursor = cursor.getPrev();


    }
    public void displaySlide(int x)
    {
        System.out.print("******************************");
        System.out.print(" " + x + " ");
        System.out.print("******************************\n\n");
        System.out.print(cursor.getSlide().toString());
        System.out.print("\n******************************");
        System.out.print(" " + x + " ");
        System.out.print("******************************\n");
    }
    public int currentSlide()
    {
        SlideNode temp = new SlideNode();
        temp = head;
        int position=1;
        while(temp!=cursor)
        {
            temp = temp.getNext();
            position++;
        }
        return position;
    }
    public int listLength()
    {
        System.out.println("In Length of List metho");
        SlideNode nodePtr = head;
        int answer = 1;
        while(nodePtr != tail)
        {
            System.out.println("In Length of List loop");
            answer++;
            nodePtr = nodePtr.getNext();
        }
        return answer;
    }
    public boolean removeCurrentSlide() 
    {
        if(cursor!=null)
        {
            cursor = cursor.getPrev();
            cursor.getNext().getNext().setPrev(cursor);
            cursor.setNext(cursor.getNext().getNext());
            cursor = cursor.getNext();
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
    public void addAfterCurrent(Slide newSlide)
    {
        SlideNode node = new SlideNode(newSlide);
        if(cursor==null)
        {
            addToEnd(newSlide);
        }
        else
        {
            node.setNext(cursor.getNext());
            node.setPrev(cursor);
            node.getNext().setPrev(node);
            cursor.setNext(node);

            cursor = cursor.getNext();

            if(cursor.getNext() == null)
            {
                tail = cursor;
            }
        }
    }
    public void addToEnd(Slide newSlide)
    {
        SlideNode node = new SlideNode(newSlide);
        if(isEmpty())
        {
            System.out.println("Created list");
            head = node;
            tail = node;
            cursor = node;
        }
        else
        {
            while(cursor!=null)
            {
                cursor = cursor.getNext();
            }
            tail.setNext(node);
            node.setPrev(tail);
            node.setNext(head);
            tail = node;
            cursor = node;

        }
        System.out.println("Out of addToEnd");
    }
    public boolean isEmpty()
    {
        return (cursor==null);
    }
    public boolean moveForward()
    {
        if(cursor!=tail)
        {
            cursor = cursor.getNext();

            return true;
        }
        else
            return false;       
    }
    public boolean moveBack()
    {
        if(cursor!=head)
        {
            cursor = cursor.getPrev();

            return true;
        }
        else
            return false;       
    }
    public void resetCursor()
    {
        cursor = head;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        try 
        {


            SlideList slides = new SlideList();

            System.out.println("AddToEnd");

            Slide newSlide = new Slide();
            newSlide.setData("1", "2", "3", "4", "5");
            slides.addToEnd(newSlide);
            slides.displayCurrentSlide();

            System.out.println("AddToEnd");

            Slide newSlide1 = new Slide();
            newSlide1.setData("2", "3", "3", "4", "5");
            slides.addToEnd(newSlide1);
            slides.displayCurrentSlide();

            System.out.println("AddToEnd");

            Slide newSlide2 = new Slide();
            newSlide2.setData("3", "4", "5", "6", "7");
            slides.addToEnd(newSlide2);
            slides.displayCurrentSlide();

            /*System.out.println("AddToEnd/ResetCursor");

            Slide newSlide3 = new Slide();
            newSlide3.setData("4", "5", "6", "7", "8");
            slides.resetCursor();
            slides.addToEnd(newSlide3);
            slides.displayCurrentSlide();
            System.out.println("Length of List");
            System.out.println(slides.listLength());
            System.out.println("Displaying All Slides");
            slides.displaySlides(1, 10);*/

        }
        /*catch (IOException e) 
        {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        } */
        catch (EmptyListException e)
        {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }


    }


}
```

Comment: Please consider writing an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: What is wrong with your ouput? Please explain what results you are getting and what you are expecting to get. Also consider Mark Elliot's suggestions or nobody will bother reading through all that code.

Comment: SO is not a place for your coursework

Answer (score 0):

First, most linked lists will have more than one item possibly accessing it, so the Cursor isn't an intrinsic part of the list, but of the "accessor of the list".

Second, for you to be doing something wrong, you need to know what it was you were intending to do.  We might be able to find an answer (as I did above); but, nobody knows if it is the right answer for your particular problem.  Describe the problem (providing examples) and we will do our best to describe *why* it is behaving unexpectedly.